# adding checkbox to theme customizer

Tags: theme-customizer, get-theme-mod

I have been trying to add a checkbox into the theme customizer. I have a checkbox added using this code in my functions.php

```
function theme_customizer_register_checkbox($wp_customize) {

$wp_customize->add_section( 'savior_global_options', array(
    'title'          => 'Global Options',
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'show_supporters', array(
    'default'        => true,
    'type'           => 'option',
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options' )
);

$wp_customize->add_control( 'display_supporters', array(
    'settings' => 'show_supporters',
    'label'    => 'Show supporters section',
    'section'  => 'savior_global_options',
    'type'     => 'checkbox',
) );
 }
 add_action( 'customize_register', 'theme_customizer_register_checkbox' );
```

Once I got the checkbox working. I found that when I checked the box, it wouldn't change state. It always stayed checked. I did some searching and found post on this site that was solved but didn't leave an answer. The post led me to think that I needed to change the value in my `$wp_customize->add_control()` function to a unique value. So I changed it to `display_supporters`. This solved my issue but now I can't get the value of the checkbox. When I dump this variable,

```
$supporters = get_theme_mod('display_supporters);
```

I get bool(false)

and it stays at that. no matter what I do to the checkbox. What am I missing?

Comment: Total noob, but does [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-theme-customizer-a-methodology-for-sections-settings-and-controls-part-1--wp-33238) help at all?

Comment: Yes, I got it with the code in the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this. Here is the code that got the checkbox working.

```
function theme_customizer_register_checkbox($wp_customize) {

$wp_customize->add_section( 'global_options', array(
    'title'          => 'Global Options',
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'show_supporters', array(
'default'        => true,
'transport'  =>  'postMessage'
 ) );

$wp_customize->add_control(
'show_supporters',
array(
    'section'   => 'global_options',
    'label'     => 'Show supporters section?',
    'type'      => 'checkbox'
     )
 );
 }
 add_action( 'customize_register', 'theme_customizer_register_checkbox' );
```

Then I checked for the value in the front end like so

```
if(true === get_theme_mod('show_supporters')){ do something here }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your theme modification setting isn't displaying as you're saving it as an option. You're setting it to save as an option in the `$wp_customize->add_setting` method with the `'type' => 'option'` argument.

As it's an option you could retrieve it using `get_option( 'show_supporters' )` instead. Note that 'show_supporters' is the name of the setting you've created not display_supporters.

However unless your theme already has a settings panel it's probably best to store it in your theme's modification settings. You can then use `get_theme_mod( 'show_supporters' )` to get your value. Otto on Wordpress has written a good article about [replacing option pages with the theme customizer](http://ottopress.com/2012/theme-customizer-part-deux-getting-rid-of-options-pages/).

I could only reproduce the problem with the checkbox not unchecking if the id of the add_setting and add_control methods did not match. I've included the code that worked for me below.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'show_supporters', array(
    'default'        => true,
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options'
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'show_supporters', array(
    'settings' => 'show_supporters',
    'label'    => 'Show supporters section',
    'section'  => 'savior_global_options',
    'type'     => 'checkbox'
) );
```

Comment: the checkbox does allow me to check and uncheck it but the options still doesn't work. Under this code, I get this string(0) ""

Comment: Does the value of the checkbox stay when you refresh the theme customizer? Are you using `get_theme_mod( 'show_supporters' )` to show the setting? You could also have a look at the wp_options table in your database to see what's going on. If you save your setting as an option it will be called 'show_supporters'. If you save it using the theme settings it will be called theme_mods_themename and will contain a serialised array of your settings.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for you help Dylan. It did help me look at the code a bit different